# How can I use jsdoc types in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm starting to update type definitions in Definitely Typed for [Chartist](https://github.com/gionkunz/chartist-js). I recently realized that Chartist is filled with JsDoc with type params like so:

```
 /**
   * Chartist.Svg creates a new SVG object wrapper with a starting element. You can use the wrapper to fluently create sub-elements and modify them.
   *
   * @memberof Chartist.Svg
   * @constructor
   * @param {String|Element} name The name of the SVG element to create or an SVG dom element which should be wrapped into Chartist.Svg
   * @param {Object} attributes An object with properties that will be added as attributes to the SVG element that is created. Attributes with undefined values will not be added.
   * @param {String} className This class or class list will be added to the SVG element
   * @param {Object} parent The parent SVG wrapper object where this newly created wrapper and it's element will be attached to as child
   * @param {Boolean} insertFirst If this param is set to true in conjunction with a parent element the newly created element will be added as first child element in the parent element
   */
  function Svg(name, attributes, className, parent, insertFirst) {
```

Is it possible to tell Typescript to use the JsDoc param types? If not, is it possible to to generate declaration files from JsDoc like above? I've found third party libraries like [tsd-jsdoc](https://github.com/englercj/tsd-jsdoc) but I'm curious about the official Typescript stance. I also found [Issue #2916](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2916) in the Typescript repo which says most of the work is covered but it's not clear to me from the linked issues what the outcome was.

Comment: I thought it already does. [Type Checking JavaScript Files](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Type-Checking-JavaScript-Files)

Comment: @JeffMercado I'm able to use JsDoc / Typescript for code I'm writing but not library code (included in package.json). If that's the crux of my question, I would appreciate instructions on how to tell the compiler that JsDoc is used in my library code.